# UTF-8 Telugu text not rendering correctly in terminal

Tags: command-line, python, fonts, locale, utf-8

I am trying to process telugu text with Python. Text is rendering correctly in chrome browser like this.

[image]

Unfortunately it is not rendering correctly in default terminal or python shell in terminal.

[image]

[image]

Can you help in finding what is causing the problem?

**What I have tried so far:**

Installed all available telugu fonts

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-telu-extra fonts-telu fonts-lohit-telu
```

Setup unicode support in terminal

```
locale             
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Enable `te_IN` in `/etc/locale.gen`

Setup telugu language from Language Support.

Download custom telugu fonts and load them.

None of these have solved the problem. Without proper rendering, it is very hard to understand text. Any help in troubleshooting this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out gnome-terminal doesn't support CTL(Complex Text Layout) yet. There [is an open issue](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=584160) for this.

For now, we can use Konsole which handles CTL.