# Why do I have Wayland packages installed although my system is not using Wayland?

Tags: apt, package-management, xorg, mate, wayland

I am using Ubuntu MATE 17.10. The [release notes](https://ubuntu-mate.org/blog/ubuntu-mate-artful-final-release/) never mentioned anything about Wayland, and I've always assumed this system was using the Xorg display server.

However, today I ran the usual

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
```

and noticed that the output included:

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-server0 [...]
```

I thought, that's odd. Is my system using Wayland after all?

As [suggested by Byte Commander in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43911618#43911618), I looked for running processes (using `pgrep Xorg` and `pstree`), and found Xorg but no Wayland. So I'm pretty sure Wayland is not running. I looked for Wayland packages:

```
dpkg -l | grep [Ww]ayland
ii  kwayland-data                         4:5.38.0-0ubuntu1                        all          Qt library wrapper for Wayland libraries - data files
ii  kwayland-integration:amd64            4:5.10.5-0ubuntu1                        amd64        kwayland runtime integration plugins
ii  libkf5waylandclient5:amd64            4:5.38.0-0ubuntu1                        amd64        Qt library wrapper for Wayland libraries
ii  libqt5waylandclient5:amd64            5.9.1-2                                  amd64        QtWayland client library
ii  libqt5waylandcompositor5:amd64        5.9.1-2                                  amd64        QtWayland compositor library
ii  libwayland-client0:amd64              1.14.0-1ubuntu0.1                        amd64        wayland compositor infrastructure - client library
ii  libwayland-cursor0:amd64              1.14.0-1ubuntu0.1                        amd64        wayland compositor infrastructure - cursor library
ii  libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64            17.2.8-0ubuntu0~17.10.1                  amd64        implementation of the Wayland EGL platform -- runtime
ii  libwayland-server0:amd64              1.14.0-1ubuntu0.1                        amd64        wayland compositor infrastructure - server library
ii  qtwayland5:amd64                      5.9.1-2                                  amd64        QtWayland platform plugin
```

Why do I have these packages related to Wayland even though I'm not using Wayland?

Comment: Thanks for asking this! I noticed some Wayland packages today on a trial install of Lubuntu 18.04, which particularly confused me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Thanks to [Byte Commander](https://askubuntu.com/users/367990/byte-commander) and [Eliah Kagan](https://askubuntu.com/users/22949/eliah-kagan) making suggestions [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43911775#43911775)** I was able to figure out  that these packages were installed as dependencies.

As [suggested](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43911792#43911792) I simulated removing Wayland related packages... When I tried pretending to remove *all* Wayland-related packages...

```
apt remove '.*wayland.*' -s
```

the result looked apocalyptic, with a full-screen terminal full of packages being removed, including the entire `ubuntu-mate-desktop` metapackage and all its adjuncts, the `xorg` package (oops!) and `marco` (MATE's default window manager).

But just removing `kwayland-data` only seemed to remove a couple of other mysterious packages `kwayland-integration` and `libkf5waylandclient5`...

So as Eliah Kagan [suggested](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43912020#43912020) I tried asking `aptitude why` I had these packages, for example

```
$ aptitude why kwayland-data
i   konsole              Depends    libkf5windowsystem5 (>= 4.96.0)                           
i A libkf5windowsystem5  Recommends kwayland-integration                                      
i A kwayland-integration Depends    libkf5waylandclient5 (>= 4:5.27.0+p16.10+git20161029.2052)
i A libkf5waylandclient5 Depends    kwayland-data (= 4:5.38.0-0ubuntu1)
```

Ahh! That makes sense. I installed Konsole because other terminal emulators [don't support CTL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925367/utf-8-telugu-text-not-rendering-correctly-in-terminal).

By asking `aptitude why` over and over like a persistent toddler, it's possible to find out why any particular package is required or has been installed, for example:

```
$ aptitude why libwayland-egl1-mesa
i   libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 Depends libwayland-egl1-mesa (>= 10.0.2) | libwayland-egl1
$ aptitude why libwayland-cursor0
i   libgtk-3-0 Depends libwayland-cursor0 (>= 1.9.91)
$ aptitude why libgtk-3-0
i   mate-utils Depends libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.16.2)
$ aptitude why mate-utils
i   ubuntu-mate-desktop Depends mate-utils
```

Simulating removal of packages like `libgtk-3-0` (be careful not to actually remove them...) reveals more about the dependency structures in play.

#### Conclusion

I have these packages because other packages surprisingly depend on them. Some, such as `kwayland-data`, installed as a dependency of a dependency of a package recommended by a dependency of a non-essential package I installed myself, could be safely removed, but others, such as `libwayland-egl1-mesa` are dependencies of packages integral to my system, and removing them would be disastrous! With APT's `--simulate` or `-s` flag and `aptitude` we can safely investigate these matters.

Comment: This's not a genuine explanation but only an analysis. We need to know WHY  Canonical insists integrating Wayland components into Ubuntu Desktop Environment so much that one cannot remove them readily, even when he only uses x11.