# getting rid of the Ubuntu-desktop package

Tags: mate

I'm running Ubuntu-mate 19.04.  I decided to experiment with some different desktop environments, Unity and the Ubuntu flavored gnome 3.  I got rid of Unity, but I can't seem to get rid of the Ubuntu and Ubuntu on Wayland options.  Also rather than the nice green mate login screen that comes up quick a get a strange looking purple 1 that appears to belong with regular Ubuntu.

Thanks
Dave

Answer (score 1):

I think that removing the following packages should get rid of what you are talking about.

However, be sure to review the changes to be made before you type "Y" to accept the changes so that you don't remove some packages that you want to keep. This shouldn't be an issue here but it is always good practice to review all changes.

You can run the following commands to remove `gnome-shell` and the wallpapers:

```
sudo apt remove gnome-shell ubuntu-wallpapers* gnome-shell-common gdm3
sudo apt autoremove
```

When prompted, select "lightdm" as your display manager by using the arrow keys and then press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

This should be enough to remove the `ubuntu-desktop` and other related packages as they all depend on these packages.

As far as your Wayland issue is concerned. I'm not quite sure what you are talking about because you didn't go into specifics but [according to this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1023676/why-do-i-have-wayland-packages-installed-although-my-system-is-not-using-wayland), your mate desktop does depend on libwaland so you might want to be careful removing Wayland packages.

You may be able to remove `xwayland` but I would be careful and again **make sure to review any changes before you accept the changes to be made.**

You can always press CTRL+C to exit out of a command if you don't want to accept the changes.

---

Additionally:

To list available packages, you can use a command like this example:

```
apt-cache search wayland | grep wayland
```

To list installed packages, you can use a command like this example:

```
dpkg -l | grep wayland
```

To list all the packages that depend on a certain package, you can use a command like in this example:

```
apt-cache show ubuntu-desktop | grep -i depends
```

or

```
apt-cache show ubuntu-mate-desktop | grep -i depends
```

Just remember that these dependencies all have dependencies of their own.